# Comparing polynomial and linear regression

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, linear-regression

I am tasked with finding a good model for some provided data. A quadratic model has been given and we are asked to compare the quadratic model with a simple linear regression. When comparing two linear regression models, I would normally check the residual plots (i.e. standardised residuals vs independent variable, standardised residuals vs fitted value) and normal QQ plots as well as checking the $R^2$ value and seeing which is higher. Would this methodology work for deciding whether the quadratic or simple linear model is better?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting 'quadratic model' to mean a linear regression with a quadratic term, i.e. $Y=\alpha + \beta X + \gamma X^2 + \epsilon$.

Generally, a quadratic model will always fit the given data better, but it might result in overfitting, which is not desirable. So in principle, we are comparing a more 'parsimonious' simple linear regression model with a heavier but possibly overfitting quadratic model.

The above idea of overfitting is related to your question regarding $R^2$. $R^2$ will almost always be higher (unless the data fits perfectly with a linear fit) in the quadratic model than the simple linear regression. If you wish to account for this, a metric such as [Adjusted $R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) (which penalizes the inclusion of extra variables that do not lead to large incremental increases in $R^2$) might be more appropriate.

An example where a quadratic model is arguably better than a linear model is the regression of annual wage income on age. The reason why the quadratic model is better, is that income actually peaks around middle age (55-65 years old) and then drops afterwards, so it is not truly linear.

- A quadratic model allows for a maximum to be taken around 55-65 years old. [A key difference between the two models is that a quadratic model allows for a varying slope, whereas the linar model has a fixed slope.]
- Contrarily, in the linear model, the low wages of very young people (showing a positive correlation between age and wage) and very old people (showing a negative correlation between age and wage) would partially cancel out each other's effects, and thus lead to a flatter slope overall, which is  not representative of young age and middle age (where the slope should be positive and relatively large) or old age (where the slope should be negative).

[Edit in response to comment]

Residual plots can indeed be useful for getting intuition about whether the modeling assumptions hold. For example, a great way to visualize the issue described in the second bulletpoint above is the residual plot below:

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Residual plot indicating that nonlinear fit is probably best.] |

I took the screenshot above from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/interpreting-the-residuals-vs-fitted-values-plot-for-verifying-the-assumptions), which has a very detailed discussion of how to use residual plots to gauge whether modeling assumptions hold. If your residual plots are like the leftmost screenshot in that post (the one labeled 'no problem'), then linear fit is probably best. If your residual plots are like the rightmost screenshot in that post (the one labeled 'nonlinear), then quadratic fit is probably best. [The heteroskedasticity case shown in the middle screenshot of that post is not very relevant to the question you are asking.]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So would I also be correct in using the residual plots I mentioned to see whether the modelling assumptions hold?

Comment: @HungaryGoose Just edited my answer in response to your comment. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit this is all much clearer. Just for completion, the linear model with the quadratic term will work fine with residual plots and the tests I'd do on a 'regular' linear regression model (i.e. one with no quadratic term)?

Comment: @HungaryGoose What I was discussing above was interpreting the residual plots of the simple linear regression (as it seems you understood from your comment). I am actually not very sure on how to interpret the residual plots of the regression with the quadratic term. The advice below is based on my intuition, so it could be wrong. If the residual plot looks like 'no problem', then you definitely do not need higher-order polynomial terms. If the residual plot still shows a nonlinear pattern (which I find unlikely), then my intuition says that a higher-order polynomial would fit better.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure that including the polynomial terms would mean we have to apply different rules regarding residual plots. This is useful.

Comment: However, it is generally not great practice to include too many polynomial terms, since overfitting becomes likely and it starts becoming difficult to interpret what the higher-order polynomial terms mean from a qualitative/intuitive standpoint.